# scp fails randomly

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm trying to set up a regular `scp` between two linux based systems (one with SLC5, other running Ubuntu).  I seem to be able to happily copy in one direction, but not the other.  Copying from the Ubuntu to SLC5 machine via `scp` does not always fail but seems to hang randomly.  Running `scp -v` the command always hangs at the same point:

```
 Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host feynman.hpc.susx.ac.uk, user   
 mm613, command scp -v -t ~/snoplus/db/testrelay/  OpenSSH_5.3p1   
 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009  debug1: Reading   
 configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to feynman.hpc.susx.ac.uk [139.184.80.19] port 22. 
 debug1: Connection established.  debug1: identity file   
 /home/mjmottram/.ssh/identity type -1  debug1: identity file   
 /home/mjmottram/.ssh/id_rsa type -1  debug1: identity file   
 /home/mjmottram/.ssh/id_dsa type 2  debug1: Checking blacklist file   
 /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024  debug1: Checking blacklist file   
 /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
```

Anyone got any ideas of what's going on? `/etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024` does not exist on either machine, and sometimes I am able to copy a number of files before this error appears and the command hangs.

Comment: When it doesn't hang, what's the next line? (This will tell us what it's trying to do when it hangs.)

Comment: When it doesn't hang, the next few lines (with -vvv verbose mode) are: >>>debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
>>>debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
>>>debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>>>debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7

Comment: I believe that means you are waiting for the SSH server to send its banner. This probably means TCP wrappers is hanging, possibly due to DNS or however it decides whether to allow a connection to proceed or not.

Comment: Ultimately I want to place all the scp commands within a Python script, as I have thousands of files to copy and log with a database.. the hanging is a real issue - is there a way to force an error message after hanging at this stage (the Python script has no way of differentiating between a hang and slow/large file transfer at the moment)....

Comment: It will already generate an error if it times out. If it hasn't timed out, there hasn't been any error, so no reason to generate one. As soon as it knows whether it is hanging or not, it will tell you. A better solution is to find and fix the hang. (Check TCP wrappers on the other machine, hosts.allow/hosts.deny files, DNS, and so on.)

Comment: I don't see where the error is being generated when it hangs.  Could you explain a little more where/what to check - I've never had to look into ssh/scp details before. /etc/hosts.allow has sshd: ALL, /etc/hosts.deny is empty other than comments... Thanks/

Comment: Check the hosts.allow/hosts.deny files on the other machine. Check DNS on the other machine if the hosts.allow/hosts.deny files specify a configuration that requires DNS to work. (That is, if it decides whether to allow an incoming SSH connection based on host name.)

Comment: Both /etc/hosts.deny and hosts.allow are empty on the machine doing the copying, sshd:ALL is present in hosts.allow on the server machine being copied *to*